# How to write a method to recognize words from following language

Tags: java

I'd like to start out that I'm new and in need of assistance.

**Prompt:**
Write a method, public static boolean Language(String word), to recognize words from the following language:

```
{ a^n | n is a prime number }
```

If the input "word" is from the language the method returns true and false.

Test Examples:

```
Input: aaa     true
Input: aaaaaaaa false
Input: aaaaaaa true
Input: a false
Input: aba false
```

I appreciate the help and time taken.

EDIT:

Okay so I was extremely confused on the isPrime and what to input, but at this point I'm at isPrime(String word) And compiling gives me an error at "boolean F = isPrime(word.length())" cannot be applied to (int).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Homework_2F_2

{

public static void main(String args[])

{

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a word from language \"A\" ");

String word = keyboard.nextLine();

boolean D = isTrue(word);

if(D == false)  
System.out.println("This word is not part of the language");

boolean F = isPrime(word.length());

if(F == true && D == true)  
System.out.println("This word is part of the language");  
}

//Check for language Method  
public static boolean isTrue(String word)  
{  
if(word.length() == 1)  
return false;

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)

{  
if(word.charAt(i) != 'a')  
return false;  
}

return true;
}


//Method to find if word is prime  
public static boolean isPrime(String n)

{

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your specific question is, but you might start by checking the length of the input string to see if it's prime. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) Then, check to see if every character in the string is an 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier for you if you break down the problem into smaller ones. Given the input you need to perform the following tasks:

- Get all words from the input
- Check each word if it belongs to the language

More specifically:

- Get the input (via a function argument)
- Split the input using space as separator
- for each word:

  - Check if it only contains the letter 'a'; if not, return false
  - Count the number of characters
  - Check if the number of characters is a [prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test); if not, return false
- If your function reached this point, return true

Answer (score -2):

There you go...

```
public static boolean Language(String word)
{
    if(word == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(char c : word.toCharArray())
    {
        if(c != 'a')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int len = word.length();

    if(len == 0 || len == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        if(len % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The above is the most basic method...you can do some optimizations...like instead of having two loops try to manage with one that will do both the character checking and the prime checking...

Comment: -1 for a complete answer. This is a homework problem, the student isn't going to learn anything by copying your work.